# Large scale mixed integer (quadratic) programming

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, integer-programming, quadratic-programming

Here we have this optimization problem:

Given positive semi-definite matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n }$, and matrix  $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \text{ and vectors } d \in \mathbb{R}^n,e \in \mathbb{R}^ m$, we seek to find $x$ be binary variable of length $n$

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
& \min_x x^T Ax + x^Td \\ 
& \text{subject to } B^Tx = e 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
However, $n$ can be as large as 1000. I tried cvxpy with backend sovler ECOS_bb, but it was too slow to solve.

Is there any solver that I could use to solve this problem ?

Should I linearize the objective $A$ to convert it into a mixed integer linear programming problem ?

Thanks for any advice and help !!

Comment: You can try converting to MILP. But even as MIQP, you can try Gurobi solver under cvxpy - that is likely a better solver for your problem than ECOS_BB . Note this from https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/issues/281 in 2016 regarding ECOS_BB "It is a very simple implementation and will not be very fast for big/complex models".  By contrast, Gurobi is a sophisticated state of the art MIQP and MILP solver. Mosek would also likely be better than ECOS_BB.

Comment: XPRESS is another good choice under cvxpy.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thanks for the suggestions !!